# Whitelist URLs in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, security, url

I'm installing an application server on Ubuntu 18.04 and the install manual requires whitelisting a number of URLs. How to do this in a fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04?

Please whitelist the following URLs:

```
1. 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
2. 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
3. 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
4. 3.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
5. auth.docker.io
6. charts.fluxcd.io
7. download.docker.com
8. files.pythonhosted.org
9. get.helm.sh
10. get.k3s.io
12. github.com
15. _https._tcp.download.docker.com
16. _http._tcp.repo.saltstack.com
17. _http._tcp.security.ubuntu.com
19. ntp.ubuntu.com
20. production.cloudflare.docker.com
21. pypi.org
22. pypi.python.org
23. quay.io
25. registry-1.docker.io
26. repo.saltstack.com
27. security.ubuntu.com
28. www.google.com
```

Comment: If it's a fresh install, everything should be whitelisted. Did you install `ufw` or something and add filtering?

Comment: What install manual? If you would share a link to what you are asking about, it will make it easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: "an application server" you need to do that in the application server if it is needed. Ubuntu does not blacklist URLs.